# How to fill in a dataframe with results from a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying to write a for loop in R, which calculates the distance between two vectors (the jth row of a matrix [Z], and a vector, [F1]), and puts the distance into the second column of a dataframe called results. The first column of the results is filled in with years, starting with the year 1906. So the for loop would run through this calculation for each row of [Z], and fill in each row of "results" after each iteration.  Here is the code that I have so far- the code does what I would like if I remove the for loop and run each line individually (for example, if I replace all the j's with 1), but when I add in the for loop it does not work. I don't get an error message, but none of the values show up in the results dataframe. If anyone can help me figure out what I'm missing, that would be great!

Just a side note, Z is a 97 x 22 matrix and F1 is a 1 x 22 matrix.

```
   results <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 97, ncol = 2)) 
   colnames(results) <- c("year", "distance")
   for(j in 1:97) {
    data <- as.numeric(Z[c(j),])
    data2 <- as.numeric(t(F1))
    distance <- euclidian.dist(data, data2)
    results[j, 1] <- j + 1905
    results[j, 2] <- distance
   }
   View(results)
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not indicate where you got the `euclidean.dist` function so I'll use the `dist` function in base R. We need to create some data:

```
set.seed(42)
Z <- matrix(runif(97 * 22), 97, 22)
F1 <- matrix(runif(22), 1, 22)
```

Then we run `F1` against each row in `Z`:

```
year <- 1906:2002
distance <- sapply(1:97, function(i) dist(rbind(F1, Z[i, ])))
results <- data.frame(year, distance)
str(results)
# 'data.frame': 97 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ year    : int  1906 1907 1908 1909 1910 1911 1912 1913 1914 1915 ...
#  $ distance: num  2.29 1.85 1.77 2.17 2.17 ...
```